# Deriving an equation for the right strophoid

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, differential-geometry, curves

> Let $D$ be a fixed line in $\mathbb{R^2}$. For each line $r$ non parallel to $D$ and passing through the origin $(0,0)$, let $M$ and $N$ be points on $r$ such that: $$d(M, P) = d(N, P) = d(P, A)$$ where $P = D \bigcap r$ and $A$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ on the $x$ axis, as shown below. The set of all points $M$ and $N$ when $r$ varies is called the *logocyclical* or *strophoid* curve. Determine a parametrization for this curve.
>
> [image]

A hint given in the book is that one should show that the polar equation of the strophoid (where $a = d(O, A) $) is $r \cos(\theta) = a(1 \pm \sin(\theta))$, but I haven't been able to do so. I tried using simple trigonometry and all the usual stuff but it was still out of my reach. I'd be very grateful for any help/hints.

**A little progress**: I have managed to show that if $D$ is the line $x = 1$, a parametrization for the curve is $$\alpha(t) = \left(\frac{2t^2}{t^2 + 1}, t \sqrt{1 - \frac{4t^2}{(t^2 + 1)^2}}  \right)$$

but the more general case still eludes me.

Comment: The Straphoid is more easily generated by foci of intersected ellipse sections made by inclined cutting plane on a circular cylinder radius $a$.(Roberval) Polar coords $ r/a= -\dfrac{\cos 2 \theta}{ \cos \theta}$ and parametric Cartesian coords $ x= \dfrac{u^2-1}{u^2+1},\, y= u \,\dfrac{u^2-1}{u^2+1},\, u=\tan \theta$. Hope you can correlate the method of its generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
AK=AH=ML=AI=OA\sin\theta=a\sin\theta
$$
whence: 
$$
OK=r_N\cos\theta=OA+AK=a+a\sin\theta,
\quad
OH=r_M\cos\theta=OA-AH=a-a\sin\theta.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I was making such a fuss of basic trigonometry. On the last part, though, did you mean to write $OH = OA - AH$ as opposed to $OH = OA - AK$? Also, what program did you use to create that image?

Comment: You are right about $AH$: I'll correct at once. I used GeoGebra to make the diagram: www.geogebra.org